# Angular 2 Rxjs creating action after server response

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs

I am a new in Angular2(and especially to RxJs library) and stacked on next step. My web site starts with a register page.
And after the completion of of register form i have base `service.auth.ts` method register usage

```
     registerUser(){
        this.authService.registerUser(this.registrationForm.value)
        .subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);
        })
        //this line should apear after server response from backend
        console.log('AFTER SERVER RESPONSE')
        }
```

And i recieve response like this

[image]

I read some stuff about `flatMap` method in RxJs documentation and it is claimed to be alternative to default `Promise` method `then()` - but i failed to create working instance of code that acutally implements `flatMap` method for my case

So the question is : **How can i achieve result so 'AFTER SERVER RESPONSE' message appears AFTER server response?** (not before as mentioned on previous screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for asynchronous task to complete. Move that `console.log('AFTER SERVER RESPONSE')` inside your `subscribe` block.

```
registerUser() {
        this.authService.registerUser(this.registrationForm.value)
        .subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);
           //this line should apear after server response from backend
           console.log('AFTER SERVER RESPONSE')
        });

      // anything written over here will execute before `registerUser()` returns data
     console.log('THIS WILL PRINT BEFORE SERVER RESPONSE')
}
```